# $\overrightarrow{a} \otimes \overrightarrow{b}$ looks unpleasant

Tags: math-mode, arrows

As the question says,

```
$\overrightarrow{a} \otimes \overrightarrow{b}$
```

looks rather unpleasant because the arrow over the a is so much lower than the arrow over the b. I'm not sure that just raising the arrow over the a would lead to a visually pleasing result... but I thought I'd ask if anyone had any suggestions.

Edit: [image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can force the two arrows to be on the same level by adding a `\vphantom` instruction in the argument of the first `\overrightarrow` instruction. "vphantom" is short for "vertical phantom"; a vertical phantom has no width (and is therefore invisible) and has the same height and depth as its argument. For your purposes, the argument of the `\vphantom` command may simply be the character used in the second `\overrightarrow` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\overrightarrow{a\vphantom{b}} \otimes \overrightarrow{b}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum**: If you find yourself using a lot of `\overrightarrow` instructions and don't wish to have to keep track of whether the heights of some of the arrows have to be adjusted, you could create a command such as `\rarrow` (short for "right arrow"):

```
\newcommand{\rarrow}[1]{\overrightarrow{#1\vphantom{b}}}
```

Here, `b` is chosen as the argument of the `\vphantom` command because it has a full-height ascender. The preceding MWE could then be rewritten as

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\rarrow}[1]{\overrightarrow{#1\vphantom{b}}}
\begin{document}
$\rarrow{a} \otimes \rarrow{b}$
\end{document}
```

**Further addendum**, prompted by a great comment by @sigur: To address the possibility that both elements of the tensor product consist of characters that either do not contain ascenders or only half-height ascenders (such as "t" and "j"), you could define a command named, say, `\tensorpr`, as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for less-cramped positioning of arrows
\newcommand{\tensorpr}[2]{\overrightarrow{#1\vphantom{#2}} 
                  \otimes \overrightarrow{#2\vphantom{#1}}}
\begin{document}
$\tensorpr{a}{b}$
\end{document}
```

Note the symmetric use of the `\vphantom` instructions. By the way, I'd recommend using the `amsmath` package because it causes the arrows to be typeset ever so slightly higher above their arguments, leading to a less "cramped" look.

Comment: Nice. What about this command: `\newcommand{\oarrow}[2]{\overrightarrow{#1\vphantom{#1#2}}\otimes\overrightarrow{#2}}` to write the tensor product with the `\vphantom` using both arguments so that in case of no letters with ascenders, everything works.
`

Comment: @Sigur -- thanks for this great comment! I've incorporated your idea in a new addendum that sets up a command I call `\tensorpr` and uses two `\vphantom` instructions.